# Javascript/html keep url params

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

say I provide someone with a link to my page that looks like the following

> www.linkone.com?something=ten

When they visit the page, the param will be visible within the url for that page.  If on that page I then have a link like so

```
<a href="linktwo.html"> Link Two </a>
```

When they click on it, Link Two's url will look like

> www.linkone.com/linktwo.html

Is there any way to add the param from the first link onto any other links within the page?  So when they visit Link Two, I want to url to end up being

> www.linkone.com/linktwo.html?something=ten

I know it is probably possible via javascript, but the homepage has a lot of links on it to other pages within the site, and I need to param on all links.  What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What if the new link itself has new parameters or you want to delete an old parameter? What then?

Comment: I have tried local storage, but not too sure I trust this method.  I have also tried a javascript solution which gets the param and then sets the attr value of my link with this param appended, but when you have a lot of links this seems very inefficient.

Comment: p.s. the parameters will always be the same for each user, they will never change

Comment: A short javascript snippet can modify all `a` elements when the page loads and append the querystring - you would not need to do them individually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is possible (with php):

```
<a href="http://www.linkone.com/linktwo.html?something=
<?php echo $_GET["something"]; ?>"> Link Two </a>
```

Comment: Not an exact answer for this question.

Comment: @ebilgin but this is possible

Comment: PHP isn't tagged so this isn't suitable unless you ask if the OP would consider using server-side for something that can be done client-side. **Questions have tags for a reason.**

Comment: What if he has different querystring key different from "something" or he has keys more than one?

Comment: Upvoting this answer is a joke to SO.

Comment: @ebilgin I couldn't agree more. Sese Schneider should ask if php would be an option before offering a language that isn't tagged or offer a solution using a language that is tagged and have this as an optional choice.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('a:not([href=#])').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = this.href + "your param";
});
```

Comment: What if anchor has target attribute ?

Comment: If you update the links href you need to update the ones that are dynamically added also, with this you can use event delegation like so $("body").on("click", 'a:not([href=#])', function()...

Comment: This solution partially work. If anchor has an target="_blank" attribute this solution ignore the opening new window behavior.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is:

```
$('a:not([href=#])').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Getting query-string parameters from current page URL.
  var query = location.search.substr(1);

  // Getting URL from current link;
  var url = new URL($(this).attr('href'));

  // Updating query-string parameters of current link.
  url.search += (url.search.indexOf('?') == 0 ? '&' : '?') + query;

  // Getting the link target.
  var target = $(this).attr('target');

  // Navigating to new URL.
  if (target) {
    window.open(url.toString(), target);
  } else {
    location.assign(url.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: Here we are again, what if anchor has a target="_blank" attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve a similar function is to use cookies or session. When a user visits your site with additional param, set a cookie on the parent page with that param so that it would be available for other calls/links. You could do that in session as well. session would retain the value till the session times out and cookie expires based on the expiry date set for it.

[Link to Cookie Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can update anchors `href` attributes at Document Ready. Below code solution for current HTML querystrings carries over the selected anchors href attributes.

```
var selectedAnchors = $("a");

selectedAnchors.each( function () {

    var itemHref = $(this).attr("href");

    if ( itemHref.indexOf("?") > -1 )
        itemHref += "&";
    else
        itemHref += "?";

    itemHref += location.search.substr(1);

    $(this).attr("href", itemHref );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Just replace word "something" with your own parameter.

Thanks

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    var something = getUrlParameter('something');
    var newURL = a+"?something="+something;
    window.location.href = newURL;
});

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>
```

Comment: What if anchor has a target attribute.

Comment: He didn't mentioned and clearly provided the example which shows that there will be only link no parameters.